# Of all the countrys on the planet, which one has the highest number per capita and/or the largest population of coffee lovers ??

Tags: coffee-culture

There are many coffee lovers all over the world and coffee is becoming in fashion and an addiction. So, which country has the highest number per capita and/or the largest population of any on earth?

Answer (score 1):

China maybe? My second option is India. As "coffee lover" is a blurry definition, I assume you wanted to ask household consumption of coffee per country.

If you check [this website](https://www.caffeineinformer.com/caffeine-what-the-world-drinks), you'll see the Northwestern Europe consumes the most coffee per person. The first country is Finland with 9.6 kg. Interestingly, contradictory to my beliefs, Italy is 18<sup>th</sup> with 3.4 kg. Also, Turkey is not included in the study.

If you check the total consumption of countries, the first two countries are USA and Brazil with a very close consumption of 971 and 969 tonnes.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's the largest, but in Israel the estimated consumption is 10 kg of coffee for a person per year, which is a LOT. [Source](https://www.ynetnews.com/articles/0,7340,L-4176899,00.html):

> The annual coffee consumption in Israel is estimated at 10 kilograms (22 pounds) per person.

(The data in [this other answer](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/a/4513/124) is probably using a different measure system)